# Adding an object to an array (with Hooks in React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to add an object to an array in React using Hooks,
I'm doing a chat, and I want to add a new message to the array of messages,

I tried this :

```
setMessages([...messages, newMessage]);
```

Here is more of the code :

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    socket.open();

    loadMessages();

    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("send message", data => {
      setMessages([...messages, data]);
    });

    socket.on("delete message", data => {
      setMessages(messages.filter(message => message.id !== data.id));
    });
  });

async function loadMessages() {
    try {
      const dataMessages = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/chat/messages`
      );
      setMessages(dataMessages.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

but I got the **TypeError: "messages is not iterable"**,

can someone help me? thank you !

Comment: Please show all the relevant code.  where is `messages` created?  What is its default value?

Comment: This works if messages is created as en empty array. `let array = []; array = [...array, 'Hi'];`

Comment: @DavinTryon messages default value is "false", and becomes an array with datas after the loadMessages() in the useEffect. I just added some code

Comment: @sebastienbarbier messages default value is "false", but after the function loadMessages is executed in the useEffect, it becomes an array with objects inside

Comment: It is an issue of incorrect typings. You should not assign it to false, even if you eventually assign it to an array. You are trying to spread/iterate a boolean value instead of an object/array. Use this instead: `const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting messages as boolean value 
Change this

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState(false);
```

to

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
```

Then add elements to array, also dont mutate the messages array.

Hope it helps

Comment: great, if it helped you feel free to up vote and accept the answer, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Use a more appropriate default value (of the same type):

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
```

Then, you will *always* be able to spread `messages`.

Answer (score 1):

This happen because the initial value of messages is boolean and you can't spread it into the new messages array.

Try:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Now all you need to do is to accept this amazing answer, slowly move your mouse to the check sign, click on it. @Versifiction

Answer (score 0):

Use:
const [mesages, setMessages] = useState([]);

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since ibtsam already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.